# Find and replace value in 2 Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have two tabs in a google sheets file
TabA pulls data from a database once a day it returns 70k records (so ideally I don't want to run this multiple times in a day
TabB pulls data from the database every hour on a timed trigger and it pulls only records that were updated in the last hour.

I now want to "push" the updated values in Tab B into the corresponding record on TabA

So tab A will look something like below containing ALL records

| userID | name | active | tags |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 19 | Jane | true | 15 |
| 72 | Peter | true | 5 |
| 5 | Jon | true | 7 |
| 33 | Tim | true | 0 |

Tab B would look like this only containing the records that has changed over the last hour (when the script has run)

| userID | name | active | tags |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 19 | Jane | false | 15 |
| 72 | Peter | true | 9 |

Now I want to effectively replace the records for these two users in tab A with their updated versions contained in Tab B

I was considering VLookup, but considering how the changes can be either column 2, 3 or 4 that may not be the best approach.

I also looked at using Match, but that too from what I read would not really do it.

Comment: Function can't replace values. They can only appear output.

Comment: Can we merge it and where there is a duplicate take from tab B instead of TabA?

Comment: Maybe you can do that, and use the [UNIQUE function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10522653) to remove the duplicates. Just make sure that when you merge the data the values on tab B are at the top Unique `Returns unique rows in the provided source range, discarding duplicates. Rows are returned in the order in which they first appear in the source range.`